# Reach the end of the tableview without using 'numberOfRowsInSection' delegate method iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to add a view after the last cell of tableview. I need to define the frame for it. If I want to add something before the first cell, then I can set the frame as

```
refreshHeaderView = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.view.bounds.size.height,320.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

But how to find the y coordinate of the frame of view to be set after the last cell.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableview subclasses scrollView, so, to answer your question, you can use contentSize, however, can you use the footerView to achieve what you want anyway ?

Comment: How do you obtain the value for y-coordinate of contentoffset of the end of tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code:

```
refreshHeaderView = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.tableView.contentSize.height, 320.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
```

Comment: That will add refreshHeaderView at the bottom of the tableview