# How can I add a subview to the bottom of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I am using the EGOTableViewHeader class provided from:

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/

I am able to display my view at the top of my UITableView:

```
refreshHeaderView = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, 320.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
refreshHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:237.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshHeaderView];
```

**How can I figure out the Y-Coordinate to show this view at the bottom of the last cell in my UITableView?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reach the end of the tableview without using 'numberOfRowsInSection' delegate method iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912217/reach-the-end-of-the-tableview-without-using-numberofrowsinsection-delegate-met)

Comment: There is no resolution for that post.

Comment: Sure there is, just set the footerView.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more specific?  Are there more cells that scroll into place?  I'm guessing your tableview has more cells than the screen real-estate provides, so do you want your view to come into place as the last cell is scrolled upward?

Edit:
Personally, the idea of figuring out content height on a table view is too messy, especially since you have to add the subview yourself, rather than have the UITableView manage it for you.  There is a more elegant solution that works in my opinion:

Create an extra section (that doesn't have to have any rows associated with it).  Then implement the function

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

Return the view you were meaning to add as a subview under your main table.  That should do the trick.

Comment: that is correct, I want my view to come into place as the last cell is scrolled upward.

Comment: Added my solution, let me know if you have questions/concerns

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the very bottom of a `tableView` by using `self.tableView.contentSize.height`.

So your code becomes

`refreshHeaderView = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.tableView.contentSize.height, 320.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];`



Once you have the position just add the view to your tableView as you did with the previous one.